# Install cocoapods before CI integration

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, cocoapods, xcode-server

Trying to run a bot on my Xcode Server. The project uses cocoapods, however they are ignored via git.

So I am trying to 'pod install' for the bot integration via a script.

That looks like this:

[image]

However when I run the bot / integration I get this error:

```
Trigger Error Trigger exited with non-zero status 127
```

[image]

How can I properly run pod install for my bot?

Comment: @Biclops providered a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39521369/pod-install-in-xcode-bots-trigger). It helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Better if edit your `.gitignore` and commit Pods folder.